# Dimension of the Grassmannian of lines of an hyperplane section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians

Let $X$ be an isotropic Grassmannian, $Pic(X)=\mathbb Z$ (for example $X$ is a projective space or a quadric hypersurface). Consider a global section $s \in \Gamma(X,L)$, where $L$ is the generator of the Picard group such that
$$
\text{codim}\,(Z(s) \subset X)=1.
$$
Now consider $G(1,X)$ that is the Grassmannian of lines contained in $X$. Then we can define
$$
Y:=G(1,Z(s))=\{[\mathbb P^1] \in G(1,X): \mathbb P^1 \subset Z(s) \subset X\}.
$$
I know that $Y$ can be seen as the zeroes of a global section $s' \in \Gamma(G(1,X),Q)$ where $Q$ is the dual of the tautological bundle $Q^\vee$ that naturally comes with $G(1,X)$.

Can we say something about $\dim Y$ or about $\text{codim}\,(Y \subset G(1,X))$? I expect that the codimension is two, but I don't understand how to prove it.